# How to convert a nested model into a JSON in EmberJS?

Tags: ember.js

I have a nested EmberJS model hierarchy:

```
{
  name: 'abc',
  type: 123,
  rules: {
           condition1 : 'value1',
           condition2:   'value2'
           subrule: {
                       subcondition1: 'value1',
                       subcondition2: 'value2'
                     }
         }
```

I am not using Ember DS. 
The problem is to give the model object arrays to a previewer which consumes JSON and not a typical get/set API of Ember Objects.

Comment: I usually end up writing a `ToJSON` method in my models (like [this](https://github.com/MilkyWayJoe/hello-ember-router/blob/master/HelloEmberRouter/Scripts/app.js#L39-50)) cause I'm working with .NET backend. Not ideal, but does the job. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to JSON encode your object, you can use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) method

```
JSON.stringify(obj)
```

here is a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ycs9u/)

Comment: Thanks, but my question is specifically to EmberJS model.